# Cannot run the code sample

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just download the sample file in Android Developers site (https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html), then open this using Android Studio.

But I found the run button is disable and I can't find any way to execute this (just like this http://chuantu.biz/t5/34/1474269694x3394677986.jpg).

Any one can tall me how to run this file in Android Developers?

Comment: Pro tips: there's no need to add `any one can help me` or similar to your questions, especially in the title, where it will just create work for editors. Please also refrain from `thx` and other txtspk abominations - if writing full words is too much trouble, Stack Overflow is probably not for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set "app" or similar on here:

[image: one]

**UPDATE1** (Maybe it's the problem)

That project it's not a new gradle project then maybe you imported wrong, you must import the project as `"Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle...)"`

[image: two]

Comment: Thank for reply, I tried file->import project but the run button still disable. like this (http://chuantu.biz/t5/34/1474271221x2918530629.jpg)

Comment: @kanonmoon close all project and reopen Android Studio and try to import using the  import option like the image

Comment: Thank this work now, sorry about asking this pool question.

Comment: @kanonmoon I'm glad to listen that, You can accept the answer or upvoted to another users.